# Duplicating columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a way to duplicate all columns in a dataframe, and have the duplicated column as the original name with a '_2' on the end.

Example:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
start_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d2 = {'col1':[1,2],'col1_2':[1,2],'col2':[3,4],'col2_2':[3,4]}
end_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NB. this answer demonstrates a generalization of the process*

Without any loop for generating the dataframe, you can simple use the `repeat` method of the columns index.

Then you can set columns names programmatically with a list comprehension.

For 2 repeats:

```
end_df = start_df[start_df.columns.repeat(2)]
end_df.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a in start_df for b in ('', '_2')]
```

output:

```
   col1  col1_2  col2  col2_2
0     1       1     3       3
1     2       2     4       4
```

Generalization:

```
n = 5

end_df = start_df[start_df.columns.repeat(n)]
end_df.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a in start_df
                            for b in ['']+[f'_{x+1}' for x in range(1,n)]]
```

Example n=5:

```
   col1  col1_2  col1_3  col1_4  col1_5  col2  col2_2  col2_3  col2_4  col2_5
0     1       1       1       1       1     3       3       3       3       3
1     2       2       2       2       2     4       4       4       4       4
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. The others answers worked as well, but the fact that the columns are next to each other, rather than at the end of the dataframe is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
start_df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

for column in start_df.columns:
    start_df[column + '_2'] = start_df[column]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.insert()` function:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
start_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for i, col in enumerate(start_df.columns):
    start_df.insert(i+1, col+'_2', start_df[col])
start_df
```

output:

```py
Out[1]:
   col1  col1_2  col2_2  col2
0     1       1       3     3
1     2       2       4     4
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it worked. What I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Akmal Soliev's answer: If you want the duplicated columns directly after each original column, you have to adjust his code as following:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)    

for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    df.insert(df.columns.get_loc(col)+1, col+'_2', "")

df
```